# Jquery Ajax based tree

Tags: jquery, ajax

i wants to create a dynamic list of countries, states and cities with the arrows on the left side and checkboxes. if user click on the arrow then all the states of the selected countries should be display like a tree view, if user click on the any states then all the cities should be displays under that state.

i am working on Jquery, Ajax, PHP , MySql

any help , suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jstree.com/ is probably a good resource for you. I am just starting to use it now, for something similar to what you are asking.